# PureText broken by Firefox 17.0.1?

Tags: firefox

[PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) is one of my favorite utilities because it saves you from having to paste stuff into Notepad to remove rich formatting. However, in Firefox 17.0.1 it no longer works.  I have the option enabled to make a sound when I do a paste with it, and the sound still plays, but nothing is pasted.

I tried changing the hot key assignment to "Win+Number pad 0" and "shift+ctrl+z" just in case it was a hot key conflict in Firefox, but it didn't help.

Any idea what changed in Firefox 17 that would cause PureText to break?

Comment: Mozilla listed here the changes that can break addons: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/11/08/compatibility-for-firefox-17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve Miller knows about the bug and is looking for ways to fix it in the next PureText release, which should also be better compatible with Windows 8 (where <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is reserved by the OS to cycle through toaster notifications).

The bug has already been [reported to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=819899).

As a quick workaround for now you can change the default PureText hotkey to something like <kbd>F11</kbd> for example.

Comment: Good news... before I saw your post I got a reply from Steve Miller who says he's testing a fix and it should be released soon.  Side note: I'm using Windows 7 (and am able to use PureText outside of FF), and I did try different hot keys.  That being said, I went ahead and tried F11 as you suggested, and, for some strange reason that key works.  Perhaps it's just when the hot key in PureText is a key combo (Ctrl/Win/Alt) that it's busted.  Anyhow, thanks for the link to the Mozilla bug report. :-)

Comment: Steve has released the new PureText version (v3.0), and I can confirm that it once again works in Firefox! :-)  Grab it from the PureText link in the original post above, or here's the same link again: http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/ ( @Karan, perhaps you'd like to edit your answer accordingly?)